# Mysql, index is ineffective: "using where"

Tags: mysql, indexing

I would like to add an index to my table because the "article_linkage" table contains 420 000 000 records. But always get "Using where" in Extra column.

```
explain SELECT
          al.article_id AS article_id,
          al.criteria_value AS criteria_value,
          al.criteria_id AS criteria_id

        FROM `xy`.`article_linkage` AS al

        WHERE
           al.type_id = 3885
           AND al.type_type = 2
           AND al.genart_id IN (402)
```

And the result:

```
SIMPLE, al, ref, test_index, test_index, 18, const,const,const, Using where
```

the index:

```
test_index  BTREE   
type_type   A   
type_id     A   
genart_id   A
article_id  A
criteria_value  A
```

How create a good index for this query?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a composite index of the 3 fields that you use on your where condition.

```
create index my_idx on article_linkage(genart_id, type_id, type_type);
```

Comment: Since it looks like `genart_id` might be used for a list of "IN" things, put it last, not first.

Answer (score 0):

[The docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/explain-output.html) say:

> Unless you specifically intend to fetch or examine all rows from the table, you may have something wrong in your query if the Extra value is **not** *Using where*

So in other words: You use a `where` clause in your query. That is all its meaning. It is neither good nor bad.